# Extract all keys in the second level of nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to extract all keys in second level of 2d dictionary but python interpreter return NameError.  my expected result is ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

```
>>> adict
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'b': {'aaa': 444, 'ccc': 666, 'bbb': 555}, 'a': {'aa': 111, 'cc': 333, 'bb': 222}})

>>> all = [ele for ele in adict[ww].keys() for ww in ['a', 'b']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ww' is not defined
```

Answer (score 5):

You're close. You just need to re-order your loops:

```
all = [ele for ww in ['a', 'b'] for ele in adict[ww] ]
```

To understand why, think about how you'd write a normal `for` loop:

```
all = []
for ww in ['a', 'b']:
    for ele in adict[ww]:
        all.append(ele)
```

Notice the order of the loops remains the same. Also, I've dropped the `.keys()`, it isn't necessary because iteration on a `dict` by default happens over the keys.

---

[You can also be awesome like Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652155/how-to-extract-all-keys-in-second-level-of-2d-dictionary/45652179?noredirect=1#comment78262729_45652179) and do this:

```
In [265]: set().union(*adict.values())
Out[265]: {'aa', 'aaa', 'bb', 'bbb', 'cc', 'ccc'}
```

`*adict.values()` returns a list of inner dictionaries, whose keys are unpacked and then added to a set. Some pointers:

1. Order not guaranteed (even on python3.6)
2. Duplicates are dropped

Comment: Something like `set().union(*adict.values())` might also be suitable... (which will extract all keys as a set instead of a list - which might be useful if you don't want to specify exact keys and don't want duplicates)

Comment: Note: also calling `.keys()` is unnecessary, and could be expensive (Py2). Also: `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(adict.values()))` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

```
adict = {'b': {'aaa': 444, 'ccc': 666, 'bbb': 555}, 'a': {'aa': 111, 'cc': 333, 'bb': 222}}

[key for nested_dict_key, nested_dict_value in adict.iteritems() for key, value in nested_dict_value.iteritems()]
```